# Changing android search dialog text color

Tags: android, android-theme

I styled my App using a theme as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

```
<style name="MyThemeNameHere" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#eee</item>
<style>
```

It works like a charm in most of the App. The background is pretty dark while the text color is bright and text looks good and is easy to read.

Now in the [search dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingTheSearchDialog) that android creates for me the background is white, but the text color picks up my style and gets very bright and thus extremely hard to read. I tried also setting `android:background` to a dark color - This fixed the problem in the search dialog, but caused all textview, etc to get a dark background rather than transparent.

I want to either set the the color or the background *only* on the search dialog. How do I do this?

Comment: You might get help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547226/android-styling-theming-of-just-search-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Mark Philip the solution can be found in this question:
[Android Styling/Theming of just Search Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547226/android-styling-theming-of-just-search-dialog)

Basically it should be styled like so

```
<style name="master" paret="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#EEEEEE</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#EEEEEE</item>
</style>
```

The root cause was that I styled the `android:textColor` which should never be styled.